# Access Denied when syncing between s3 buckets on different AWS accounts

Tags: permissions, amazon-s3, synchronization, aws-cli

I'm trying to setup sync between two buckets on different AWS accounts.

I got `cp` working with:

```
@ubuntu:~$ s3cmd cp -v s3://src/dir/ s3://dest/folder --recursive
```

I am the user who owns `/src/dir` and I've added:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Id": "Policy1477299702471",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Stmt1477299696163",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::awsid:user/name"
        },
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*"
    }
]}
```

To the bucket permissions policy on the test bucket.

Now I'm after `aws sync` to work, as using `s3 cp` is not recommended for using with cron.

I tried

```
user@ubuntu:~$ aws s3 sync --dryrun s3://src/ s3://dest/ --region eu-central-1
```

but I get access denied:

> fatal error: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjects operation: Access Denied

How can I get access denied if this is the user who owns the bucket, and get sync running?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The cause of your `ListObjects` error is that you assigned permission to access the *contents* of your bucket (`arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*`) but you did not give permissions **to the bucket itself** (`arn:aws:s3:::bucket`). The `ListObjects` command requires access to the bucket.

To test this, I did the following:

- Used two AWS accounts: Account A, Account B
- Created `bucket-a` in Account A
- Created `bucket-b` in Account B
- Created an IAM User `user-a` in Account A with permissions to access `bucket-a`
- Added a Bucket Policy to `bucket-b`:

  ```
  {
    "Id": "CopyBuckets",
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Sid": "Stmt1",
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": [
          "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-b",
          "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-b/*"
        ],
        "Principal": {
          "AWS": [
            "arn:aws:iam::<account-a-id>:user/user-a"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
  ```

I then triggered the sync by using `user-a` in Account A:

```
aws s3 sync s3://bucket-a s3://bucket-b --profile user-a
```

It worked successfully.

Comment: Hi are the regions the bucket are in not relevant?

Comment: Amazon S3 bucket names are globally unique, so ARNs (Amazon Resource Names) for S3 buckets do not need the account, nor the region (since they can be derived from the bucket name). However, when calling the `aws s3 sync` command, the region is important because you should send the request to the bucket that is *doing* the copy (the source bucket).

Comment: Watch out for missing permissions on items that are synchronised. When performing a sync you also need to use the --grants option to specify that the canonical name of the Account B is granted permission otherwise the objects that are synced will only be accessible to the original owner from Account A.

Comment: If you want to have the correct owner on the objects copied into the destination bucket, you must run the sync command from the destination account not the source account. So the logic here would be flipped.

Comment: Or use `--acl bucket-owner-full-control`